# ExtJS 5 Upgrade - Viewport unrecognized class name / alias

Tags: javascript, extjs, upgrade, viewport, extjs5

My application is working fine in ext js 4.2.1 but when I upgrade I am unable to get the viewport to load correctly. The view port is in a different file and loads initially but then I get the

> Error: [Ext.create] Unrecognized class name / alias: App.view.MainViewport

I have tried requiring the the viewport file but that is not working. Any help would be much appreciated.

app.js

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true)};
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'extjs5.1.1/ux');
Ext.require(['Ext.tip.QuickTipManager','Ext.container.Viewport', 'Ext.plugin.Viewport','Ext.layout.*','Ext.form.Panel','Ext.form.Panel', 'Ext.form.Label','Ext.grid.*','Ext.data.*','Ext.tree.*','Ext.selection.*', 'Ext.tab.Panel','Ext.ux.TabCloseMenu'] );
Ext.onReady( function() {
   Ext.application({
     name : 'App',
     appFolder: 'extapp',
     launch: function() {
       Ext.create('App.view.MainViewport');
     }
   });
});
```

MainViewport.js

```
Ext.define('App.view.MainViewport', {
   extend : 'Ext.container.Viewport',
   alias : 'widget.MainViewport',
   layout: {
     type: 'border'
   },
   initComponent: function() {
       console.info("initializing view");   
   }
});
```

Comment: Please post the structure of the viewport file, the file name structure and the content of the initial app.js. Without that, nothing to be seen here.

Comment: I added the code that I am using in the question.

Comment: Please check whether your use of `Ext.loader` and `Ext.Loader` are really correct. I have put all your other code into a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/t6f) and it works in Ext 5.1.1.

Comment: That was a typo here. I have the correct in my actual file. I have a lot of required files, models, stores, and controllers. But I commented all those out and still got the same error as above. It also tells me that I am synchronously loading the MainViewport file.

Comment: I can't see `App.view.MainViewport` in the `require` list. Have you tried adding it?

Answer (score 0):

I did try using the MainViewport in the require but that returned an error and empty page. I actually found the problem and was able to fix it!
The problem was that in the MainViewport file, I had a requires and then the required files also required other files. In order to find the files that were causing the errors, I had to traverse through all of the required files and find the failing one. I did this by commenting out each required file everywhere and eventually found the culprit. Then, my page rendered correctly. Thanks for your help!